# Выполнение функции при закрытии окна браузера

Tags: javascript, ajax, браузер

Пытаюсь сделать счётчик посетителей сайта, я видел его на множестве ресурсов, но что-то не задалось.

Есть база, в которой хранится число посетителей, есть php-скрипт, который должен добавлять в базу +1 при входе юзера (это работает с событием `ready`) и -1 при его выходе с сайта (с этим проблема). Есть функция, которая отправляет ajax-запрос на этот php-скрипт, и есть событие `onbeforeunload` или `unload`, вызывающее функцию.

Не знаю, кто из этого списка виновный, но функция умудряется срабатывать аж после закрытия страницы, при её следующей загрузке. То есть функция срабатывает только при обновлении страницы или её восстановлении (*cntrl+shift+T*) даже раньше события `ready`, но если страницу просто закрыть, то вообще никакого эффекта не будет. Тестировал только в *firefox*, т.к. этот браузер приоритетен.

Сам код:

**HTML:**

```
<script>window.onunload = putout();</script>
```

**JS:**

```
function putout() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./php/process.php",
        data: {
            'function': 'putout',
            'def': def,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

        },
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
include ('./php/connect.php');
mysql_query("UPDATE numb SET numb=numb-1");
```

Ещё я наслышан о том, что опера и вовсе игнорирует эти события, тогда как вообще кроссбраузерно реализовать счётчик посетителей сайта?

**P.S. Текст уже тыщу раз переисправляли, это уже совсем не мой стиль изложения, примите к сведению. Вообще ненавижу возможность лезть без спроса в мои публикации сторонним людям, это ОЧЕНЬ раздражает.**

Comment: Независимо от всего написанного, у пользователя может просто оборваться интернет, поэтому даже при работоспособности on[before]unload стоит заводить таймаут и автоматически уводить пользователя в оффлайн, например, минут через пять. А ещё такие вещи лучше хранить в чём-нибудь более быстром чем MySQL.

Comment: По теме вопроса — асинхронные ajax-запросы при закрытии вкладки вроде как не работают, нужно синхронные отправлять.

Comment: @andreymal ну предположим, тогда как реализовать с помощью таймаута? Если я не заблуждаюсь, то JS отрабатывает локально, если пользователь выйдет с сайта, то и все его таймеры тоже канут вместе с ним. Запустить некую машину с особым php кодом, который будет постоянно сверять раннюю версию таблицы юзеров с новой и отсеивать тех, кого не оказалось в новой? Я размышлял над этим, но, кажется, это как-то неправильно.

Comment: Именно что правильно. Может, не конкретно так (сильно зависит от потребностей и реализации сервера), но суть такая.

Answer (score 1):

Метод выполняется при загрузке страницы, но не срабатывает при выгрузке из-за некорректного использования.

Этот код

```
window.onbeforeunload = putout();
```

выполнит функцию **сразу после загрузки** скрипта, еще до готовности страницы. В то же время, к событию не присоединится никакой хэндлер, так как функция вернёт undefined.

Чтобы указать хэндлер для события, надо убрать вызов метода:

```
window.onbeforeunload = putout;
```

Теперь функция не будет вызываться при старте, а будет вызываться перед выгрузкой.

**В любом случае,** это некорректный подход к подсчету пользователей.

Comment: Заменил на window.onbeforeunload = putout; - функция вовсе перестала вызываться.